# $Gr_2^+(\mathbb R^4) \cong S^2 \times S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $Gr_2^+(\mathbb R^4)$ be the oriented Grassmanian of 2-planes in $\mathbb R^4$. How would one go about showing that this is diffeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^2$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but: $\text{Gr}_2^{+}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is acted on transitively by $\text{SO}(4)$. $-I$ acts trivially, so this action factors through the quotient, which is isomorphic to $\text{SO}(3) \times \text{SO}(3)$ (this can be seen for example using quaternions). It suffices now to show that the stabilizer of a point is $\text{SO}(2) \times \text{SO}(2)$.

Comment: Here I am making implicit use of a fact which I believe to be true but which I admittedly don't know enough differential geometry to prove: let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which a compact Lie group $G$ acts smoothly and transitively with stabilizer $H$. Then $G/H$ has a natural smooth structure and the map $G/H \to M$ given by $g \mapsto gm$ (for $m \in M$ such that $\text{Stab}(m) = H$) is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: For what's its worth, you belief is true.  In fact, your map is an equivariant diffeomorphism, so is a little bit better.  The only proofs I know of all this involve picking an invariant metric (doable because $G$ is compact) and using some Riemannian geometry (geodesics and normal bundles of orbits).

Comment: @Jason: Cool. Is it still true when $G$ is noncompact or is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $G/H \simeq M$ is a fairly simple thing to prove that doesn't invoke any Riemannian geometry nor compactness of $G$.  This is done in chapter 9 of Lee's "Smooth Manifolds," for example.

Comment: @Eric: thanks for the reference! (For anyone else's reference,  this is Theorem 9.24 in Lee.)

Comment: @Eric:  I think I was thinking of the proof that $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H$ is an $H$-principal bundle, or the more general case that $M\rightarrow M/G$ is a principal bundle when $G$ acts with the same conjugacy class of isotropy group at every point.

Answer (score 2):

The diffeomorphism can be nicely explicited as follows. Lift the transitive $SO(4)$ action on $\mathbb{Gr}^+_2(\mathbb{H})$ to its universal covering $\mathrm{Spin}(4) = S^3 \times S^3$ via the canonical covering representation
$$
S^3 \times S^3 \to SO(4) \qquad (p,q) \mapsto L_p \circ R_{q^{-1}}
$$

where we identify $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, the sphere $S^3$ is the group of unit norm quaternions, $L_*$ is left multiplication and $R_*$ is right multiplication by the quaternion $*$ (note that taking the diagonal $p=q$ and identifying $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the imaginary quaternions $\mathrm{Im}\mathbb{H}$, this restricts to the canonical covering $S^3 \to SO(3)$).

The $S^3 \times S^3$ action on $\mathbb{Gr}^+_2(\mathbb{H})$ is then
$$
(p,q)\Pi^+ = p \Pi^+ q^{-1}
$$
where $\Pi^+$ is an oriented plane.

To compute the isotropy of the oriented plane $\mathbb{C}^+$ with basis $1, i$, note that
$p \mathbb{C}^+ q^{-1} = \mathbb{C}^+$
implies that $L_p \circ R_{q^{-1}}$ restricts to a rotation in $\mathbb{C}^+$, thus
$$
pzq^{-1} = e^{i\theta} z, \qquad\text{for all } z \in \mathbb{C}
$$
Taking $z = 1$, $z=i$, it follows that $p = e^{i\theta} q$ and
$p i = e^{i\theta} i q$ so that
$$
p i = i ( e^{i\theta} q ) = i p \qquad
e^{i\theta} i q = (p)i = e^{i\theta} q i \Longrightarrow qi = iq
$$
so that both $p, q$ are complex.

Thus the isotropy of $\mathbb{C}^+$ is $S^1 \times S^1$, and the covering transformation descends to the explicit diffeomorphism
$$
S^3/S^1 \times S^3/S^1 \to \mathbb{Gr}^+_2(\mathbb{H}) \qquad (p S^1,q S^1) \mapsto p \mathbb{C}^+ q^{-1}
$$
where $S^3/S^1$ is the 2-sphere, since it identifies with the Riemmann sphere $\mathbb{C}P^1$ via the slope map $S^3 \to \mathbb{C} \cup \infty = \mathbb{C}P^1$, $z + wj \mapsto w/z$, where $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$.

*Remark:* the same arguments can be used to compute the isotropy of the $S^3 \times S^3$ action on the Grassmanian of non-oriented planes $\mathbb{Gr}_2(\mathbb{H})$ by noting that now $L_p \circ R_{q^{-1}}$ restricts to a rotation or a rotation and reflection in $\mathbb{C}^+$, thus we also have the possibility
$$
pzq^{-1} = e^{i\theta} \bar{z}, \qquad\text{for all } z \in \mathbb{C}
$$
which implies that $p,q$ anti commute with $i$, so that $p, q$ belong to $S^1 j$. The isotropy is thus given by $(S^1 \times S^1) \cup (S^1 \times S^1)j$ and is disconnected, in this case.

Comment: This approach completes @Qiaochu Yuan's answer.