# Show that $G_E=\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, quaternions

I am stuck at the problem below.

**(I am using two identification $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{S}=$ unit quaternion.)**

> Show that $G_{E}=\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$

Firstly, giving terminology, $M$ (or is oriented $2-$planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$) is a set of equivalence classes of pair of two orthonormal elements $(v,w)\in \mathbb{S}^3\times \mathbb{S}^3$ where the $(v_1,v_2)\sim (w_1,w_2)$ if they are related by an element in $SO(2)$. (we can also think as $(v_1,v_2 )\sim(w_1,w_2)$ $\iff $ the two pairs are in same oriented plane.)

And $G_E$ is an isotropy subgroup(or stabilizer) of group action of $\mathbb{S}^3\times \mathbb{S}^3$ on $M$ at $E=[(e_1,e_2)]$ where $$e_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0  \end{bmatrix}\hspace{4mm}e_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Here, the action of $\mathbb{S}^3\times \mathbb{S}^3$ on $M$ is induced action by a map $f:\mathbb{S}^3\times \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow SO(4)$ such that$$(p,q)\cdot [(v,w)]=f(p,q)\cdot [(v,w)] $$
where $f(p,q)\cdot v=pvq^{-1}$ for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{H}$. The multiplication is quaternion multiplication. It might be helpful to refer this '[The Quaternions and $SO(4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/459675/523306)'

In this regards, we can consider $\mathbb{S}$ as a unit quaternion group.

I am thanking for any hint or answer in advance.

Comment: Need a clarification. How exactly the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{S}^3\times \mathbb{S}^3$ is defined? $SO(2)$ gives us $2\times 2$ matrices. But Elements of $S^3\timesS^3$ are in $\mathbf{R}^4\times \mathbf{R}^4$right?

Comment: @PSG  You are right. The problem given to me is little sloppy. But I think this just means that $(v_1,v_2)\sim (w_1,w_2)$ if and only if $(v_1,v_2)$ and $(w_1,w_2)$ are in same oriented 2-plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Of course, oriented plane means if $(v,w)$ is a basis of a plane $P$ and if $P=[(v,w)]$, then $P\neq [(w,v)]$.

Comment: Again, $p,q$ are elements of $S^3\subset\mathbf{R}^4$. So, how $pvq^{-1}$ is defined?

Comment: @PSG Sorry I forgot to mention that. $p$ and $q$ are unit quaternion elements and $v\in \mathbb{H}$ is also a quaternion element. So we can define that as just a multiplication in $\mathbb{H}$. I will edit it :)

Comment: I don't know if this helps, anyway this is my attempt. I tried to write down the element $f(p,q)$ in matrix form. So, $1$st column is $pq^{-1}$, $2$nd column is $piq^{-1}$, $3$rd column is $pjq^{-1}$ and last one is $pkq^{-1}$. Now when we multiply $E=[(e_1,e_2)]$ with this matrix, we ought to get $[pq^{-1} , piq^{-1}]$. Feel free to show my mistakes.

Comment: So, if $(p,q)$ is a stabilizer we should have $(pq^{-1},piq^{-1})\sim (e_1,e_2)$

Comment: So, for some $A, pq^{-1}=Ae_1\Rightarrow A=pq^{-1}{e_1}^{-1}$ and $ piq^{-1}=Ae_2=pq^{-1}{e_1}^{-1}e_2$. This might help.

Comment: $\Rightarrow iq^{-1}=q^{-1}i,$ i.e $q\in$ stabilizer of $i$ So, of the form $q_1+q_2 i$ with norm $1$. So, $q\in S^1$

Comment: @PSG Thank you I will think about that!

Comment: @LevBahn I was also stuck in this, and it took me some time to find just the right quaternionic argument, no matrix calculation needed: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4369486/98101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $G_E = \{(p,q)\in S^3\times S^3: [(p\,e_1\, q^{-1}, p\,e_2\, q^{-1})] = [(e_1, e_2)]$.

Here's a computational way to figure out begin to figure $G_E$:  Write $p = p_0 + p_1 i + p_2 j + p_3 k$ and similarly for $q$.

Then $p \, e_1 q^{-1} = pq^{-1} \in \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{1,i\}$.  In particular, the $j$ and $k$ components of $pq^{-1}$ must vanish.

Noting that $q^{-1} = \frac{\overline{q}}{|q|^2} = \overline{q}$, we see that the vanishing of the $j$ and $k$ components of $pq^{-1}$ is equivalent to \begin{eqnarray} -p_0 q_2 + p_1 q_3 + p_2 q_0 - p_3 q_1 &= 0\\
-p_0q_3 - p_1 q_2 + p_2 q_1 + p_3 q_0 &=0\end{eqnarray}

Likewise, the fact that $p\, e_2 \, q^{-1} = piq^{-1}$ has no $j$ and $k$ components is equivalent to \begin{eqnarray} p_0q_3 + p_1 q_2 + p_2 q_1 + p_3 q_0 &=0 \\-p_0 q_2 + p_1 q_3 - p_2 q_0 + p_3 q_1 &= 0 \end{eqnarray}

We can view these four equations together as a linear system where the coefficents are the $qs$ and the variables are $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$.  In other words, this is equavalent to $$\begin{bmatrix} -q_2 & q_3 & q_0 & -q_1\\ -q_3 & -q_2 & q_1 & q_0 \\ q_3 & q_2 & q_1 & q_0\\ -q_2 & q_3 & -q_0 & q_1  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p_0\\ p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$

Now the $P$ vector is non-zero because $|p| = 1$, as $p\in S^3$.  Thus, the $Q$ matrix must have zero determinant in order to have a solution to this matrix equation.  The determinant (according to Wolfram alpha) is $ 0 =4(q_0^2 + q_1^2)(q_2^2 + q_3^2)$

Thus, either $q_0 = q_1 = 0$ or $q_2 = q_3 = 0$.  We next actually show the first case cannot occur.  (If you aren't worried about the *oriented* $(1,i)$ plane, then both cases do arise).

So, assume $q_0 = q_1 = 0$.  Then the above matrix equation forces $p_0 = p_1 = 0$ as well.  That is, $q = q_3 j + q_4 k$ and similarly for $p$.  Note that $p_3^2 + p_4^2 = q_3^2 + q_4^2 = 1$ because they are just $|p|^2 = |q|^2 = 1$ in disguise.

Now, compute $$p\, e_1\, q^{-1} = pq^{-1} = (p_3 q_3 + p_4 q_4) + (-p_3 q_4 + p_4 q_3)i$$ and likewise $$p\, e_2\, q^{-1} = piq^{-1} = (-p_3 q_4 + p_4 q_3) + (-p_3 q_3 - p_4 q_4)i.$$

It follows that the matrix of the transformation $e_n \mapsto p e_n \, q^{-1}$ is given by $\begin{bmatrix} p_3 q_3 + p_4 q_4 & -p_3 q_4 + p_4 q_3\\ -p_3 q_4 + p_4 q_3 & -p_3 q_3 - p_4 q_4 \end{bmatrix},$ which has determinant $-(p_3^2 + p_4^2)(q_3^2 + q_4^2) =-1$ (with thanks, again, to Wolfram alpha).

In other words, when $q_0 = q_1 = 0$, we get an orientation reversing map of the plane, so it doesn't map the *oriented* plane to itself.  This gets rid of that case.

Thus, we are left with the case that $q_2 = q_3 = 0$.  In other words, $q = q_0 + q_1 i \in S^1\subseteq S^3$.  It's not too hard to see using the $4\times 4$ matrix above that $p_2 = p_3 = 0$, so $P$ has this form.  All this shows that $G_E\subseteq S^1\times S^1$.

Thus, to conclude the problem, we must show that $S^1\times S^1\subseteq G_E$.  Or, said another way, for any element of the form $(e^{i\theta}, e^{i\phi})\in S^3\times S^3$, that $e^{i\theta} P q^{-i\phi} = P$ where $P$ is the oriented plane $\operatorname{span}\{e_0, e_1\}$.  I will leave that calculation to you.